# android modify url conent for webview

Tags: java, android, webview

My problem is sending a url request, catch the result, modify the result and show it in a webview in a java application.
I have a big application, used c++ code with opengl es for the "native gameplay" and different frontend build's for different target devices.

In my Android Version I want to add something like news page. For this i have a server with news. I send a request to my server url (containing a specific slug for platform version, language code etc.) and receive data in .json format, what I have to format with my own header, banner, style etc.

eg -> urlRequest -> https://myserverip.com/news/?slug=android&language=de returns me

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "general":[
            {
                "news_id": "31",
                "title": "The title of my news",
                "text":"news Text.."
            } 
            ... 
        ]
    }
}
```

So far I have a DialogFragment class what contains a WebView as member. I played around with the WebViewClient class but at the end i was not able to catch the result before displaying it.
Every time I see the documentation of WebView / WebViewClient i look for a point were i can sneak into getting the url result.

Can someone help me explaining this web technology in easy code or even help me with my problem in detail?

Comment: I've improved the code formatting for you. The box in which you enter your question actually has a bar with controls that you can use for formatting purposes. Alternatively, if you're familiar with markdown, you can directly format the content in the textbox itself, or [see here for editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: More on topic: you probably *don't* want to use a `WebView` for displaying the Json content. Instead, make the http request, parse the Json response and populate a layout with that content. Based on the type of data that you're trying to display, your layout will probably contain at least an `ImageView` for the banner and a `ListView` for the news items. There are lots of of examples out there that describe these steps in more detail.

Comment: I think one keyword is "filtering" the webpage. I found a good tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/android-web-apps-using-android-webview.html#intercepting-webview-http-requests but this shows how to act with resources like images. Whats about the displayed Text? I also can load the WebView with my contet, but i need to get the content of my url.

Comment: i nearly figure it out by loading a the url by a httpclient in a ascy thread. but if i load the url, my .css is not loaded. This i placed in the same folder as the baseUrl. my code so far: webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/html/library/main.html", outputString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my approach was to complicated for my problem (thanks to MH. for pointing me to this).

Instead I catch the URL request via HttpClient, parse it and give it as html string direct to the view. Sadly this must done in a separate thread (or using external java sources, like [Volly](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html))

class NewsLoaderTask extends AsyncTask {

```
private WebView webView;

public void init(WebView _webView)
{
    webView = _webView;
}

protected String doInBackground(String... urlStrings) {
    try {
        URI webUrl = new URI(urlStrings[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(webUrl));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            String responseString = out.toString();
            out.close();

            return responseString;
        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("NewsFragment", "exepction: " + e.toString());
    }
    return "";
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO parse my text

    // The baseurl points to the path with the .css and as entry point for gfx
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/html/library/", outputString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

}

In my WebView I create a NewsLoaderTask instance and initialize it with my webview as parameter (for displaying the text)

```
NewsLoaderTask newsloaderTask = new NewsLoaderTask();
newsloaderTask.init(webView);
newsloaderTask.execute(getArguments().getString("url"));
```